# python depth-first search recursion

Tags: python, recursion, microsoft-distributed-file-system

i am trying to make a python dfs connecting island with recursion...

the program works fine, however on some cases there are logical error in which the output is incorrect

For example

```
o o o

o x x

o o o the output is 1 which is correct.
```

However , on other cases

```
o x o

o x o

o o o the output is 2 which is incorrect.
```

Here is my full code that includes dfs function

```
row = int(input("Enter Row : "))
col = int(input("Enter Col : "))

# declare array baru namanya peta
peta = []

# array 2 dimensi
# Masukkin smua input ke array petas
for i in range(0,row):
    line = input()
    peta.append(line)


store = []
# declare array baru nama visited
visited = []
for i in range(0,row):
    visited.append([])

    # buat column di row i false smua
    for j in range(0,col):
        visited[i].append(False)

def dfs(i,j):
    visited[i][j] = True
    a = row-1
    b = col-1
    #peta[i][j] = store[a][b]
    for i in range(i,row):
        for j in range(j,col):
            if(visited[i][j] == True):
                return 1
            else:
                if(peta[i][j] == 'x' and visited[i][j] == False ):                  
                    #top left array
                    if(i == 0 or j == 0):
                        dfs(i+1,j+1)
                        dfs(i+1,j)
                        dfs(i,j+1)                  

                    #bottom left array
                    elif(i == a and j == 0):
                        dfs(i-1,j)
                        dfs(i-1,j+1)
                        dfs(i,j+1)

                    #top right array
                    elif(i == 0 and j == b):
                        dfs(i,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j)

                    #bottom right array
                    elif(i == a and j == b):
                        dfs(i,j-1)
                        dfs(i-1,j-1)
                        dfs(i-1,j)

                    #west array
                    elif(i >= 1 and j == 0):
                        dfs(i-1,j)
                        dfs(i-1,j+1)
                        dfs(i+1,j)
                        dfs(i,j+1)
                        dfs(i+1,j+1)

                    #north array
                    elif(i==0 and j>=1):
                        dfs(i,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j)
                        dfs(i,j+1)
                        dfs(i+1,j+1)

                    #east array
                    elif(i>=1 and j==b):
                        dfs(i-1,j)
                        dfs(i-1,j-1)
                        dfs(i,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j)

                    #south array
                    elif(i==a and j>=1):
                        dfs(i,j-1)
                        dfs(i-1,j-1)
                        dfs(i-1,j)
                        dfs(i-1,j+1)
                        dfs(i,j+1)

                    #middle array
                    else:
                        dfs(i-1,j-1)
                        dfs(i-1,j)
                        dfs(i-1,j+1)
                        dfs(i,j-1)
                        dfs(i,j+1)
                        dfs(i+1,j-1)
                        dfs(i+1,j)
                        dfs(i+1,j+1)

                else:
                    #peta[i][j] = 0
                    return 0

numberofisland = 0
for i in range(0,row):
    for j in range(0,col):
        if((peta[i][j] == 'x' and visited[i][j] == False)):
            dfs(i,j)
            numberofisland+=1





print(numberofisland)
```

in my opinion, my logical error is i visit the visited node twice , however there seems no error in my arrays. Can you give some suggestion about where my mistake is?

Thank you very much for your time,  cheers

edit : i have updated into full code version as community requested ( how to call the function, global variable, etc )

Comment: How did you call it in the program?

Comment: Where did you use the return value of the DFS function?

Comment: it was in main program `if((peta[i][j] == 'x' and visited[i][j] == False)):
   dfs(i,j)
   numberofisland+=1`

Comment: Since you only have two return statements in the entire function, which are "return 0" and "return 1", your function can only return either 0 or 1, which is probably wrong, so make sure that you haven't made any copy-paste errors. Also, it would be helpful if you included the entire script in your question, so that people can run it for themselves.

Comment: Also, be more clear about what your function is supposed to do: Find the number of [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) in a graph? And are Xs that are adjacent diagonally considered to be part of the same component (island), or only Xs that are directly to the left, right, top or bottom?

Comment: each time x is found, it was supposed to check 8 direction for another x to do depth-first search until no x can be connected..  @Odysseas

Comment: I meant what is the definition of the problem that you want to solve. And as @leyanpan said, please update your question to show how you call the dfs function (and what are the values for some global variables that you use). You have not included all of your current solution, so your question is not [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Odysseas   i have updated some of it, please do check it out, cheers :)

Comment: You are using `i` and `j` both as parameters in your function and as iteration variables... I don't think that is the intention.

Comment: @darkknight I'm pretty sure that the loop inside the "dfs" function is not something you want. Since you are doing DFS, what do you need the loop for? Recursion will help you find all adjacent xs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things in your code do not make sense:

1) If you want to return a value from the `dfs` function, this value should have some meaning and it should be used. If you only call a function for its side-effects, then you can just `return` with no value. In this case, it looks like to me as the purpose of the `dfs` function is to update the `visited` array, so you do not need to return `1` or `0` or anything.

2) When you do a depth-first search in a graph, you start at a node, and you visit its connected nodes recursively. If you have a for-loop inside the `dfs` function which visits a big part of the graph, ignoring connections, then you are not doing DFS. Generally, you only need to recursively call the `dfs` function on the connected nodes.

3) The way your function looks right now, it seems that it will always return `1` before making any recursive calls.

Also take note of the following good practices for Python code:

1) Avoid constructs like `if expression == True:`. Instead use `if expression:`. Also instead of `if expression == False`, use `if not expression`.

2) Avoid using parentheses around the conditional expression in `if` and `elif` clauses, it is not neccessary, unlike C or Java. For example, instead of `elif (a == b):` use `elif a == b`.

3) Add a [docstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring) at the top of a function, to describe what the function does (see my code below for an example).

From what I understand, you want for each call of the `dfs` function to visit all connected xs that form an island. You can do this with the following code:

```
def dfs(i,j):
    '''
    This function starts from the square with coordinates (i,j).

    The square (i,j) should be an 'x', and also unvisited.

    This function will keep visiting all adjacent 'x' squares, using a
    depth first traversal, and marking these squares as visited in the
    @visited array.

    The squares considered adjacent are the 8 surrounding squares:
    (up, up-right, right, down-right, down, down-left, left, up-left).
    '''

    # The range checks have been moved to the beginning of the function, after each call.
    # This makes the code much shorter.
    if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= row or j >= col:
        return

    # If we reached a non-x square, or an already visited square, stop the recursion.
    if peta[i][j] != 'x' or visited[i][j]:
        # Notice that since we don't do something with the return value,
        # there is no point in returning a value here.
        return

    # Mark this square as visited.
    visited[i][j] = True

    # Visit all adjacent squares (up to 8 squares).
    # Don't worry about some index falling out of range,
    # this will be checked right after the function call.
    dfs(i-1,j-1)
    dfs(i-1,j)
    dfs(i-1,j+1)
    dfs(i,j-1)
    dfs(i,j+1)
    dfs(i+1,j-1)
    dfs(i+1,j)
    dfs(i+1,j+1)
```

Comment: thank you very much for you feedback. i thought a loop is necessary to traverse the whole array. But it seems that recursion will do just fine. thank you once again, cheers :)

Comment: @darkknight If you find that my answer helped you solve your problem, please go ahead and accept it (or upvote it). That's what StackOverflow [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).